# Apache rewrite rules in both config and .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite

I have a CakePHP application hosted in a virtual host (Apache 2.4) which works OK.  Now in the internal network where the virtual host name cannot be routed so I have to use the web server IP.  And since this server hosts multiple applications I have set up an Alias like this in a config file:

```
Alias /abc "/var/www/cake/audio/webroot"
<Directory "/var/www/cake/audio">
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
Require all granted
AllowOverride all
RewriteBase /abc
</Directory>
```

The problem is by specifying AllowOverride all, the RewriteBase in .htaccess  defaults to / which overrides the config file.

How can I make RewriteBase equal to / when accessed using the virtual host and RewriteBase equal to /abc when access using the IP?

Comment: I think this is not a cakePHP question - It should go to ServerFault since it relates to Apache.

Comment: Question copied to http://serverfault.com/questions/750353/apache-rewrite-rules-in-both-config-and-htaccess